# Python function not working with seemingly correct string path

Tags: python, regex, sequence

I have the following code (it changes the string/filepath, replacing the numbers at the end of the filename + the file extension, and replaces that with "@.exr")

I was doing it this way because the name can be typed in all kinds of ways, for example:
r_frame.003.exr  (but also)
r_12_frame.03.exr
etc.

```
import pyseq
import re

#create render sequence list
    selected_file = 'H:/test/r_frame1.exr'

    without_extention = selected_file.replace(".exr", "") 
    my_regex_pattern =  r"\d+\b"
    sequence_name_with_replaced_number = re.sub(my_regex_pattern, "@.exr" ,without_extention)
    mijn_sequences = fileseq.findSequencesOnDisk(sequence_name_with_replaced_number)
```

If I print the "sequence_name_with_replaced_number" value, this results in the console in:
'H:/test/r_frame@.exr'

When I use that variable inside that function like this:

```
mijn_sequences = fileseq.findSequencesOnDisk(sequence_name_with_replaced_number)
```

Then it does not work.

But when I manually replace that last line into:

```
mijn_sequences = fileseq.findSequencesOnDisk('H:/test/r_frame@.exr')
```

Then it works fine. (it's the seems like same value/string)
But this is not an viable option, the whole point of the code if to have the computer do this for thousands of frames.

Anybody any idea what might be the cause of this?

After this I will do simple for loop going trough al the files in that sequence. The reason I'm doing this workflow is to delete the numbers before the .exr file extensions and replace them with @ signs. (but ognoring all the bumbers that are not at the end of the filename, hence that regex above. Again, the "sequence_name_with_replaced_number" variable seems ok in the console. It spits out: 'H:/test/r_frame@.exr' (that's what I need it to be)

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: What i'm doing is converting a filepath URL, into a filepath sequence URL.
So i'm converting this: -> H:/test/r_frame1.exr
into this: --> H:/test/r_frame@.exr


using regex and the fileseq library.

Based on a file sequence I generate the correct filepaths using that regex.
When the filepath is a variable, I cannot insert it into that function. But when i type that exact same path into the fileseq function, then it works.

Comment: I edited the question and gave a more complete picture of what the code is doing.
Can someone help me to reopen the question the way it is now? I believe the problem can now be replicated by everyone.

Comment: One potentially important detail which is missing is what exactly `fileseq` and `fileseq.findSequencesOnDisk` are. As it is I cannot run your code to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. the problem as stated was correct, every time I did a cut and past from the variable value in the console and treated it as manual input it worked.

Then I did a len() of both values, and there was a difference by 2! What happend? The console added the ''
But in the generated variable it had those baked in as extra letters. i fixed it by adding cleaned_sequence = sequence_name_with_replaced_number[1:-1] so 'H:/test/r_frame1.exr' (as the console showed me) was not the same as 'H:/test/r_frame1.exr' (what I inserted manually, because I added these marks, in the console there are showed automatically)